# How do i check to see if an object has already been instantiated?

Tags: php

Is it possible to check and see if an object has already been instantiated with php? I have a mysql class that other pages instantiate to use its methods and what i did was make a log that logs all queries. I noticed that mysql is opened 3-4 times at a time rather than one. So i need to verify if the object is instantiated and if not it wont create another one and open another useless connection.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a perfect case for the Singleton pattern.

```
class Connection
{
    /**
     * @var Connection
     */
    private static $instance;

    private static $config = array();

    private function __construct()
    {
        // whatever you need in here, just keep the method private
    }

    public function __clone()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException;
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException;
    }

    public static setConfig(array $config)
    {
        self::$config = $config;
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `__sleep`/`__wakeup` loophole.

Comment: @Wrikken I was rushing it before anybody else answered ;)

Comment: Ha, and you still lost to me :P But you got the upvote because I was to lazy to copy it from the manual. If you link to the relevant portion of the manual I'll delete mine & upvote yours.

Comment: @Wrikken Copying it from the manual would have saved me time, I typed my answer. Also, I like `new self()` better than grabbing the class name from `__CLASS__`

Comment: no, don't make it private: that will only result in a Warning, and still a usable class.... Exceptions must be thrown or fatal errors triggered.

Comment: @Wrikken Gah, I fail. I'm not a fan of the Singleton pattern and don't use it often

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a [singleton](https://web.archive.org/web/20110305073558/http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **instanceof** operator to check if a given variable is of a specific class:

```
if ($db instanceof DatabaseClass) :
```

Read more about it here: http://php.net/instanceof

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `is_object`, as an a class has no type but just has memory allocation, so using `is_object` on a class name will only return a string, when you instantiate an object by using the new keyword, and object is created in the memory and has it's objective type.

Test Case:

```
class HelloWorld{}

$a = is_object(HelloWorld);
$b = is_object(new HelloWorld);

var_dump($a, $b);
```

Results:

> bool(false) bool(true)

Comment: This does not work for me. Without the 'new', php assumes its a constant. You have to create an object of that class and pass the object variable to the is_object function.